# Error when trying to use Wine: zsh: bad CPU type in executable: wine

Tags: wine, macos-bigsur

So I am getting this error when I try to run the command wine on my command prompt. I think it's because I am on BigSur and need a 64-bit download but I can’t find a 64-bit download.
So could someone please help me with this.

Comment: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Wine-ARM64-macOS-Initial-Patch